# Error handling in Python - something is opaque

Tags: python

I wonder, why does the 2nd code works well even when the "page" isn't in the url (meaning, it handles the error well and continues), whereas the 1st one 
ends with the error `PageNotInteger`

```
# 1
# error
try:
    page = request.GET.get('page')
except PageNotAnInteger:
    page = 1
except EmptyPage:
    page = paginator.num_pages

data = paginator.page(page)




# 2
# ok
try:
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    data = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    page = 1
    data = paginator.page(page)
except EmptyPage:
    page = paginator.num_pages
    data = paginator.page(page)
```

Comment: Presumably it is the `paginator.page()` call that throws the exception? Without a full traceback and details about what this code is supposed to do or where `paginator` and the custom exceptions come from, there isn't much we can do but speculate here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is Django's [`Paginator` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/#paginator-objects) - and you're right of course, it is the `page` method that raises the exception.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: sigh, if only people would actually use tags properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `paginator.page(page)` call that raises the exception; the `page` value retrieved from the request isn't a valid page.

The calls in the exception handlers on the other hand don't use the `page` value from the URL; you set specific values that *are* valid. You could just inline those into the `paginator.page()` calls:

```
try:
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    data = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    data = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Comment: how did knowing that it was Django's Paginator class help you to answer my question?

Comment: @imatahi: because then I could look up the documentation as to what it was supposed to do. Context is *everything*.

Comment: what it is supposed to do is irrelevant. it has to do with try except only.

Comment: @imatahi: in hindsight, perhaps, but providing context makes it far easier to follow what is happening and what *should* happen. Don't just drop random code into a question and expect people to insta-recognise what goes on.